# MySQL WHERE with comma separated string

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have seen some related, but have been unable to get it to work correctly. Hopefully this is easy for someone!

I basically am receiving values from an API in a comma separated string. I am trying to use a WHERE clause where I can use this string. Let me provide example.

**Edit**
A user fills out a form and the data is saved into a table, where one of the columns is called "Allergies". I am now looking to use that column which could look like `"Egg,Milk,Peanuts".`

I have built a query that will return recipes for the user and this needs to take into account each of the values in the string.

So I can manually have this work correctly by using this syntax:

```
...
WHERE a.AllergyName = 'Egg' || a.AllergyName = 'Milk' || a.AllergyName = 'Peanut'
...
```

Does anybody know how I can dynamically do this?

Comment: How are you getting those values from API? For i.e. with the use of another sql or via GET method etc.?

Comment: I actually updated the question. I realize that it is not actually coming from the API direclty, but is from another table. I realize that is a big difference! Sorry

Comment: "Packed" value columns (such as your "Allergies" CSV column) do mean simpler database designs, but they also mean that queries operating on them are more difficult to be SARGable, consequently they have poor performance. Can you alter the database design at all or are you stuck with it?

Comment: It could be updated..but even if it is coming from multiple rows. How could I get this same query I posted in my WHERE clause with that? Would that just be a WHERE IN type of situation?

Comment: Adding table schema in your question will be really helpful.

Comment: My main question really is if there was an operation i could use to separate the list with custom text. Such as a regex with substring...I couldn't quite wrap my head around that actually.

Comment: what do you mean by custom text? If data coming from a Form is stored in a table than you can easily compare it using `in` operator as given in answer below. If it's not possible in your case, then please explain why.

Comment: I just mean custom text as using an OR operator versus an AND operator to connect multiple values in the where clause.

Comment: You can use `OR` for static/fixed values as you've used in question, but `in` with a subquery will be more effective if you want it dynamically.

Comment: Ok...I will see what I can do with the IN operator.

Comment: you can refer my answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming from your question that you are storing allergies for each user and each user has some unique identifier like `userId`.

Try following way:

```
Select *
from Table1 t1
where AllergyName in (select AllergyName from Table2 t2 
                      where userId = (put Id here))
```

Comment: In the Table2 listed here...the allergies are still listed as "Milk,Egg,Peanuts". So I feel like I still run into the same issue?

Comment: I don't get it. What's the issue here? It won't be a problem if those are comma separated values. Thats how `in` works.

Comment: The subquery will return "Milk,Egg,Peanuts". So the overall query would look like:
```Select * from Table1 t1 where AllergyName in ("Milk,Egg,Peanuts"). That is how it is supposed to be?

Comment: No. Double quotes should not be there.

Comment: Well I guess I am just not asking my question correctly, or am misunderstanding something in my setup. But for what I was asking, this should be right answer. I will keep working at it otherwise. Thanks

Comment: Actually...I realized the error which I was asking earlier. The subquery is still returning 'Milk,Egg,Peanuts'. And it can't find that allergy because that is one long string. How do I break that up into it's comma separated values?

Comment: Your result of subquery should not be a problem. It's what it supposed to be. Does AllergyName from table1 has similar values?

Comment: I'm sorry for all the back and forth...I am going to leave this as completed, and look for other solutions. Thanks

Comment: One last try: If the result of subquery is either `('Milk','Egg','Peanuts')` or `("Milk","Egg","Peanuts")`. It will works. Otherwise it won't